# Is there an apt --force-overwrite option?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I have a source package (`foo`) which produces two binary packages (`foo-a` and `foo-b`).

In version 2.0, file `/etc/foo` was moved from `foo-a` to `foo-b`.  That causes `apt upgrade` to fail with:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/foo-b_2.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/foo', which is also in package foo-a 1.0.
```

Is there a client-side solution using `apt` to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct (tm) solution to this is to fix the dependencies of `foo-a` and `foo-b` by fixing `debian/control` with:

```
Package: foo-b
Replaces: foo-a (<< 2.0)
Breaks: foo-a (<< 2.0)
```

Reference: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#overwriting-files-in-other-packages

However, If you are not the developer of this package or maintainer of the repository, you'll need a client-side solution.

---

A client-side solution that does work is to use the `--force-overwrite` option of `dpkg`:

```
$ apt download foo-{a,b}
$ dpkg --force-overwrite -i foo-{a,b}_2.0_amd64.deb
```

Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html#OPTIONS

---

However, if you are looking for a `apt`-only 1-liner, then you'll need `apt` to forward the `--force-overwrite` option to `dpkg`.  This can be done by using the `--option` described briefly in [`apt-get(8)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html#options).  [`apt.conf(5)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/apt.conf.5.html#how%20apt%20calls%20dpkg(1)) says `DPkg::options` can be used to forward options to `dpkg`.

None of those man pages clearly define the whole syntax, so after some experimentation, I found it can be done like so:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -o DPkg::options::="--force-overwrite"
...
Unpacking foo-b (2.0) over (1.0) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/etc/foo', which is also in package foo-a 1.0
...
```

Comment: It might also be possible to upgrade `foo-a`, then `foo-b`.