# How to install a Debian package in a target directory manually

Tags: debian, dpkg, chroot

I would like to learn how to manually install a Debian package (e.g., a .deb file) into a specific directory, such as `/targetdir`, as if it were the root. Later, I would like to relocate the installation to the correct path by using a command like `cp /targetdir /`.

What I tried so far, exploiting the `dpkg` utility:

```
set -eux;
cd /tmp;
apt-get update;
apt-get download unixodbc-dev;
mkdir /dpkg;
dpkg --root=/dpkg --install --recursive .
```

The problems are that:

1. dependecies are not installed automatically: how can I retrieve the list of dependencies programmatically so that to download all of them?
2. I don't know if prerm, postrm, preinst, and postinst scripts are run or not (see: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html)
3. `dpkg --root` fails as the command run inside the new root (e.g. `/bin/sh -i`) fails: the program is there but I don't know why it fails to see it. I'm inside a Docker Debian slim image.

`apt-get` does NOT seem to be able to set the installation target directory

EDIT:

What I tried after the suggestions:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim as deb_extractor
# tools needed to build the Microsoft OBDC driver for Microsoft SQL server (requirements)
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN set -eux \
    && buildDeps=' \
            gnupg \
            curl \
            ca-certificates \
            apt-utils \
            dpkg \
        ' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && mkdir -p /build/dpkg \
    && cd /build \
    && apt-get install -o DPkg::options::="--root=/build/dpkg" -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev msodbcsql17
```

fails with error:

```
------
 > [2/2] RUN set -eux     && buildDeps='             gnupg             curl             ca-certificates             apt-utils             dpkg         '     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps     && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -     && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list     && apt-get update     && mkdir -p /build/dpkg     && cd /build     && apt-get install -o DPkg::options::="--root=/build/dpkg" -o DPkg::options::="--log=/build/dpkg.log" -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev msodbcsql17:
#5 0.362 + buildDeps=             gnupg             curl             ca-certificates             apt-utils             dpkg
#5 0.362 + apt-get update
#5 1.684 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
#5 1.763 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
#5 1.798 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
#5 1.899 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
#5 3.697 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [240 kB]
#5 3.784 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [14.6 kB]
#5 5.361 Fetched 8646 kB in 5s (1738 kB/s)
#5 5.361 Reading package lists...
#5 6.137 + apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg curl ca-certificates apt-utils dpkg
#5 6.153 Reading package lists...
#5 6.892 Building dependency tree...
#5 7.079 Reading state information...
#5 7.436 dpkg is already the newest version (1.20.12).
#5 7.436 dpkg set to manually installed.
#5 7.436 The following additional packages will be installed:
#5 7.436   dirmngr gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server
#5 7.438   gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0 libbrotli1 libcurl4 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2
#5 7.438   libncursesw6 libnghttp2-14 libnpth0 libpsl5 libreadline8 librtmp1 libsasl2-2
#5 7.440   libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh2-1 openssl pinentry-curses
#5 7.440   readline-common
#5 7.444 Suggested packages:
#5 7.444   dbus-user-session libpam-systemd pinentry-gnome3 tor parcimonie xloadimage
#5 7.444   scdaemon pinentry-doc readline-doc
#5 7.444 Recommended packages:
#5 7.444   libldap-common libgpm2 publicsuffix libsasl2-modules
#5 7.819 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#5 7.819   apt-utils ca-certificates curl dirmngr gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg
#5 7.819   gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0 libbrotli1
#5 7.820   libcurl4 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libncursesw6 libnghttp2-14 libnpth0 libpsl5
#5 7.821   libreadline8 librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh2-1
#5 7.821   openssl pinentry-curses readline-common
#5 7.894 0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#5 7.894 Need to get 11.9 MB of archives.
#5 7.894 After this operation, 24.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#5 7.894 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 2.2.4 [439 kB]
#5 8.171 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 readline-common all 8.1-1 [73.7 kB]
#5 8.230 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libreadline8 amd64 8.1-1 [169 kB]
#5 8.309 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1n-0+deb11u4 [853 kB]
#5 8.542 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20210119 [158 kB]
#5 8.659 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.9-2+b2 [279 kB]
#5 8.765 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1 [69.1 kB]
#5 8.817 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1 [106 kB]
#5 8.871 Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1 [232 kB]
#5 8.976 Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.43.0-1 [77.1 kB]
#5 9.026 Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.21.0-1.2 [57.3 kB]
#5 9.078 Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2 [60.8 kB]
#5 9.129 Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libssh2-1 amd64 1.9.0-2 [156 kB]
#5 9.195 Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7 [346 kB]
#5 9.428 Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 curl amd64 7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7 [270 kB]
#5 9.527 Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libassuan0 amd64 2.5.3-7.1 [50.5 kB]
#5 9.581 Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpgconf amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [548 kB]
#5 9.744 Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libksba8 amd64 1.5.0-3+deb11u2 [123 kB]
#5 9.802 Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libnpth0 amd64 1.6-3 [19.0 kB]
#5 9.834 Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 dirmngr amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [763 kB]
#5 10.04 Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg-l10n all 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [1086 kB]
#5 10.34 Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg-utils amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [905 kB]
#5 10.58 Get:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.34.1-3 [797 kB]
#5 10.81 Get:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [928 kB]
#5 11.07 Get:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libncursesw6 amd64 6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1 [132 kB]
#5 11.16 Get:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 pinentry-curses amd64 1.1.0-4 [64.9 kB]
#5 11.22 Get:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-agent amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [669 kB]
#5 11.41 Get:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-wks-client amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [524 kB]
#5 11.57 Get:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-wks-server amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [516 kB]
#5 11.75 Get:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpgsm amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [645 kB]
#5 12.02 Get:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg all 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [825 kB]
#5 12.41 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#5 12.44 Fetched 11.9 MB in 4s (2722 kB/s)
#5 12.46 Selecting previously unselected package apt-utils.
(Reading database ... 6664 files and directories currently installed.)
#5 12.47 Preparing to unpack .../00-apt-utils_2.2.4_amd64.deb ...
#5 12.48 Unpacking apt-utils (2.2.4) ...
#5 12.56 Selecting previously unselected package readline-common.
#5 12.57 Preparing to unpack .../01-readline-common_8.1-1_all.deb ...
#5 12.57 Unpacking readline-common (8.1-1) ...
#5 12.63 Selecting previously unselected package libreadline8:amd64.
#5 12.63 Preparing to unpack .../02-libreadline8_8.1-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 12.64 Unpacking libreadline8:amd64 (8.1-1) ...
#5 12.70 Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
#5 12.70 Preparing to unpack .../03-openssl_1.1.1n-0+deb11u4_amd64.deb ...
#5 12.71 Unpacking openssl (1.1.1n-0+deb11u4) ...
#5 12.85 Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
#5 12.85 Preparing to unpack .../04-ca-certificates_20210119_all.deb ...
#5 12.86 Unpacking ca-certificates (20210119) ...
#5 12.93 Selecting previously unselected package libbrotli1:amd64.
#5 12.93 Preparing to unpack .../05-libbrotli1_1.0.9-2+b2_amd64.deb ...
#5 12.94 Unpacking libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2+b2) ...
#5 13.01 Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules-db:amd64.
#5 13.01 Preparing to unpack .../06-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.01 Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1) ...
#5 13.06 Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-2:amd64.
#5 13.07 Preparing to unpack .../07-libsasl2-2_2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.07 Unpacking libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1) ...
#5 13.12 Selecting previously unselected package libldap-2.4-2:amd64.
#5 13.12 Preparing to unpack .../08-libldap-2.4-2_2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.13 Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1) ...
#5 13.21 Selecting previously unselected package libnghttp2-14:amd64.
#5 13.21 Preparing to unpack .../09-libnghttp2-14_1.43.0-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.22 Unpacking libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
#5 13.26 Selecting previously unselected package libpsl5:amd64.
#5 13.27 Preparing to unpack .../10-libpsl5_0.21.0-1.2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.27 Unpacking libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
#5 13.32 Selecting previously unselected package librtmp1:amd64.
#5 13.32 Preparing to unpack .../11-librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.33 Unpacking librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) ...
#5 13.37 Selecting previously unselected package libssh2-1:amd64.
#5 13.37 Preparing to unpack .../12-libssh2-1_1.9.0-2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.38 Unpacking libssh2-1:amd64 (1.9.0-2) ...
#5 13.44 Selecting previously unselected package libcurl4:amd64.
#5 13.45 Preparing to unpack .../13-libcurl4_7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.45 Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7) ...
#5 13.52 Selecting previously unselected package curl.
#5 13.52 Preparing to unpack .../14-curl_7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.53 Unpacking curl (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7) ...
#5 13.59 Selecting previously unselected package libassuan0:amd64.
#5 13.59 Preparing to unpack .../15-libassuan0_2.5.3-7.1_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.60 Unpacking libassuan0:amd64 (2.5.3-7.1) ...
#5 13.63 Selecting previously unselected package gpgconf.
#5 13.63 Preparing to unpack .../16-gpgconf_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.64 Unpacking gpgconf (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 13.72 Selecting previously unselected package libksba8:amd64.
#5 13.72 Preparing to unpack .../17-libksba8_1.5.0-3+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.72 Unpacking libksba8:amd64 (1.5.0-3+deb11u2) ...
#5 13.77 Selecting previously unselected package libnpth0:amd64.
#5 13.77 Preparing to unpack .../18-libnpth0_1.6-3_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.78 Unpacking libnpth0:amd64 (1.6-3) ...
#5 13.82 Selecting previously unselected package dirmngr.
#5 13.82 Preparing to unpack .../19-dirmngr_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 13.84 Unpacking dirmngr (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 13.93 Selecting previously unselected package gnupg-l10n.
#5 13.93 Preparing to unpack .../20-gnupg-l10n_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_all.deb ...
#5 13.93 Unpacking gnupg-l10n (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.09 Selecting previously unselected package gnupg-utils.
#5 14.09 Preparing to unpack .../21-gnupg-utils_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.09 Unpacking gnupg-utils (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.22 Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
#5 14.22 Preparing to unpack .../22-libsqlite3-0_3.34.1-3_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.22 Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.34.1-3) ...
#5 14.36 Selecting previously unselected package gpg.
#5 14.36 Preparing to unpack .../23-gpg_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.38 Unpacking gpg (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.50 Selecting previously unselected package libncursesw6:amd64.
#5 14.50 Preparing to unpack .../24-libncursesw6_6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.51 Unpacking libncursesw6:amd64 (6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1) ...
#5 14.56 Selecting previously unselected package pinentry-curses.
#5 14.57 Preparing to unpack .../25-pinentry-curses_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.57 Unpacking pinentry-curses (1.1.0-4) ...
#5 14.61 Selecting previously unselected package gpg-agent.
#5 14.61 Preparing to unpack .../26-gpg-agent_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.62 Unpacking gpg-agent (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.70 Selecting previously unselected package gpg-wks-client.
#5 14.70 Preparing to unpack .../27-gpg-wks-client_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.71 Unpacking gpg-wks-client (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.76 Selecting previously unselected package gpg-wks-server.
#5 14.76 Preparing to unpack .../28-gpg-wks-server_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.77 Unpacking gpg-wks-server (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.83 Selecting previously unselected package gpgsm.
#5 14.83 Preparing to unpack .../29-gpgsm_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 14.83 Unpacking gpgsm (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 14.91 Selecting previously unselected package gnupg.
#5 14.91 Preparing to unpack .../30-gnupg_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_all.deb ...
#5 14.92 Unpacking gnupg (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 15.01 Setting up libksba8:amd64 (1.5.0-3+deb11u2) ...
#5 15.02 Setting up libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
#5 15.03 Setting up apt-utils (2.2.4) ...
#5 15.04 Setting up libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2+b2) ...
#5 15.06 Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.34.1-3) ...
#5 15.08 Setting up libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
#5 15.09 Setting up libnpth0:amd64 (1.6-3) ...
#5 15.10 Setting up libassuan0:amd64 (2.5.3-7.1) ...
#5 15.11 Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1) ...
#5 15.12 Setting up gnupg-l10n (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 15.13 Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) ...
#5 15.15 Setting up libncursesw6:amd64 (6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1) ...
#5 15.17 Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1) ...
#5 15.18 Setting up libssh2-1:amd64 (1.9.0-2) ...
#5 15.20 Setting up openssl (1.1.1n-0+deb11u4) ...
#5 15.21 Setting up readline-common (8.1-1) ...
#5 15.23 Setting up pinentry-curses (1.1.0-4) ...
#5 15.25 Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.1-1) ...
#5 15.26 Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1) ...
#5 15.28 Setting up ca-certificates (20210119) ...
#5 15.85 Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
#5 16.56 129 added, 0 removed; done.
#5 16.59 Setting up gpgconf (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 16.60 Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7) ...
#5 16.61 Setting up curl (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7) ...
#5 16.63 Setting up gpg (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 16.64 Setting up gnupg-utils (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 16.65 Setting up gpg-agent (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.49 Setting up gpgsm (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.50 Setting up dirmngr (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.74 Setting up gpg-wks-server (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.76 Setting up gpg-wks-client (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.77 Setting up gnupg (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
#5 17.79 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
#5 17.81 Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119) ...
#5 17.81 Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
#5 18.42 0 added, 0 removed; done.
#5 18.42 Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
#5 18.42 done.
#5 18.45 + curl+  https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
#5 18.45 apt-key add -
#5 18.46   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#5 18.47                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
100   983  100   983    0     0   4964      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4964
#5 19.48 OK
#5 19.50 + curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list
#5 19.51   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#5 19.51                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    88  100    88    0     0    502      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   502
#5 19.69 + apt-get update
#5 19.80 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
#5 19.85 Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
#5 19.89 Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
#5 19.92 Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye InRelease [3629 B]
#5 20.41 Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main all Packages [1088 B]
#5 20.48 Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 Packages [85.4 kB]
#5 20.56 Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main arm64 Packages [15.0 kB]
#5 20.56 Get:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main armhf Packages [13.9 kB]
#5 20.57 Fetched 119 kB in 1s (142 kB/s)
#5 20.57 Reading package lists...
#5 21.65 + mkdir -p /build/dpkg
#5 21.65 + cd /build
#5 21.65 + apt-get install -o DPkg::options::=--root=/build/dpkg -o DPkg::options::=--log=/build/dpkg.log -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev msodbcsql17
#5 21.67 Reading package lists...
#5 22.48 Building dependency tree...
#5 22.67 Reading state information...
#5 22.91 The following additional packages will be installed:
#5 22.91   autoconf automake autotools-dev libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libltdl-dev
#5 22.91   libltdl7 libodbc1 libperl5.32 libsigsegv2 m4 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 perl
#5 22.91   perl-modules-5.32 unixodbc
#5 22.91 Suggested packages:
#5 22.91   autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc libtool gettext gdbm-l10n
#5 22.91   libtool-doc unixodbc-bin sensible-utils m4-doc perl-doc
#5 22.91   libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl make
#5 22.91   libtap-harness-archive-perl
#5 22.91 Recommended packages:
#5 22.91   libtool netbase
#5 23.04 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#5 23.05   autoconf automake autotools-dev libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libltdl-dev
#5 23.05   libltdl7 libodbc1 libperl5.32 libsigsegv2 m4 msodbcsql17 odbcinst
#5 23.05   odbcinst1debian2 perl perl-modules-5.32 unixodbc unixodbc-dev
#5 23.11 0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#5 23.11 Need to get 10.8 MB of archives.
#5 23.11 After this operation, 55.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#5 23.11 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 perl-modules-5.32 all 5.32.1-4+deb11u2 [2823 kB]
#5 23.28 Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 libodbc1 amd64 2.3.11-1 [486 kB]
#5 23.74 Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 odbcinst1debian2 amd64 2.3.11-1 [99.8 kB]
#5 23.81 Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 odbcinst amd64 2.3.11-1 [21.3 kB]
#5 23.82 Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 unixodbc amd64 2.3.11-1 [51.5 kB]
#5 23.86 Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.10.2.1-1 [791 kB]
#5 23.96 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.19-2 [64.9 kB]
#5 24.03 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.19-2 [44.7 kB]
#5 24.09 Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libperl5.32 amd64 5.32.1-4+deb11u2 [4106 kB]
#5 24.61 Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 unixodbc-dev amd64 2.3.11-1 [42.4 kB]
#5 25.15 Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 perl amd64 5.32.1-4+deb11u2 [293 kB]
#5 25.26 Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.13-1 [34.8 kB]
#5 25.31 Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 m4 amd64 1.4.18-5 [204 kB]
#5 25.41 Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 autoconf all 2.69-14 [313 kB]
#5 25.53 Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 autotools-dev all 20180224.1+nmu1 [77.1 kB]
#5 25.61 Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 automake all 1:1.16.3-2 [814 kB]
#5 25.81 Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libltdl7 amd64 2.4.6-15 [391 kB]
#5 25.94 Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libltdl-dev amd64 2.4.6-15 [162 kB]
#5 26.97 Preconfiguring packages ...
#5 27.01 Fetched 10.8 MB in 3s (3700 kB/s)
#5 27.05 Selecting previously unselected package perl-modules-5.32.
#5 27.05 dpkg: regarding .../00-perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_all.deb containing perl-modules-5.32, pre-dependency problem:
#5 27.05  perl-modules-5.32 pre-depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
#5 27.05   dpkg is not installed.
#5 27.05
#5 27.05 dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/00-perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_all.deb (--unpack):
#5 27.05  pre-dependency problem - not installing perl-modules-5.32
#5 27.07 Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm6:amd64.
(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)
#5 27.07 Preparing to unpack .../01-libgdbm6_1.19-2_amd64.deb ...
#5 27.07 Unpacking libgdbm6:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
#5 27.12 Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm-compat4:amd64.
#5 27.12 Preparing to unpack .../02-libgdbm-compat4_1.19-2_amd64.deb ...
#5 27.12 Unpacking libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
#5 27.18 Selecting previously unselected package libperl5.32:amd64.
#5 27.18 Preparing to unpack .../03-libperl5.32_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
#5 27.18 Unpacking libperl5.32:amd64 (5.32.1-4+deb11u2) ...
#5 27.96 Selecting previously unselected package perl.
#5 27.96 dpkg: regarding .../04-perl_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_amd64.deb containing perl, pre-dependency problem:
#5 27.96  perl pre-depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
#5 27.96   dpkg is not installed.
#5 27.96
#5 27.96 dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/04-perl_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
#5 27.96  pre-dependency problem - not installing perl
#5 27.97 Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:amd64.
#5 27.97 Preparing to unpack .../05-libsigsegv2_2.13-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 27.98 Unpacking libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.13-1) ...
#5 28.01 Selecting previously unselected package m4.
#5 28.01 Preparing to unpack .../06-m4_1.4.18-5_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.01 Unpacking m4 (1.4.18-5) ...
#5 28.08 Selecting previously unselected package autoconf.
#5 28.08 Preparing to unpack .../07-autoconf_2.69-14_all.deb ...
#5 28.08 Unpacking autoconf (2.69-14) ...
#5 28.16 Selecting previously unselected package autotools-dev.
#5 28.16 Preparing to unpack .../08-autotools-dev_20180224.1+nmu1_all.deb ...
#5 28.17 Unpacking autotools-dev (20180224.1+nmu1) ...
#5 28.23 Selecting previously unselected package automake.
#5 28.24 Preparing to unpack .../09-automake_1%3a1.16.3-2_all.deb ...
#5 28.24 dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new automake package pre-installation script (//var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): No such file or directory
#5 28.24 dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/09-automake_1%3a1.16.3-2_all.deb (--unpack):
#5 28.24  new automake package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
#5 28.26 Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:amd64.
#5 28.26 Preparing to unpack .../10-libltdl7_2.4.6-15_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.27 Unpacking libltdl7:amd64 (2.4.6-15) ...
#5 28.32 Selecting previously unselected package libltdl-dev:amd64.
#5 28.32 Preparing to unpack .../11-libltdl-dev_2.4.6-15_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.32 Unpacking libltdl-dev:amd64 (2.4.6-15) ...
#5 28.39 Selecting previously unselected package libodbc1:amd64.
#5 28.39 Preparing to unpack .../12-libodbc1_2.3.11-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.39 Unpacking libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.11-1) ...
#5 28.51 Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst1debian2:amd64.
#5 28.52 Preparing to unpack .../13-odbcinst1debian2_2.3.11-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.52 Unpacking odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.3.11-1) ...
#5 28.58 Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
#5 28.58 Preparing to unpack .../14-odbcinst_2.3.11-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.58 Unpacking odbcinst (2.3.11-1) ...
#5 28.61 Selecting previously unselected package unixodbc.
#5 28.61 Preparing to unpack .../15-unixodbc_2.3.11-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.61 Unpacking unixodbc (2.3.11-1) ...
#5 28.66 Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
#5 28.66 Preparing to unpack .../16-msodbcsql17_17.10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.67 dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new msodbcsql17 package pre-installation script (//var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): No such file or directory
#5 28.67 dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/16-msodbcsql17_17.10.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
#5 28.67  new msodbcsql17 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
#5 28.67 dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new msodbcsql17 package post-removal script (//var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): No such file or directory
#5 28.67 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
#5 28.67  new msodbcsql17 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
#5 28.69 Selecting previously unselected package unixodbc-dev.
#5 28.69 Preparing to unpack .../17-unixodbc-dev_2.3.11-1_amd64.deb ...
#5 28.70 Unpacking unixodbc-dev (2.3.11-1) ...
#5 28.74 Errors were encountered while processing:
#5 28.74  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/00-perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_all.deb
#5 28.74  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/04-perl_5.32.1-4+deb11u2_amd64.deb
#5 28.74  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/09-automake_1%3a1.16.3-2_all.deb
#5 28.74  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QbNPep/16-msodbcsql17_17.10.2.1-1_amd64.deb
#5 28.75 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
```

Comment: Maybe you could try `apt install unixodbc-dev -o DPkg::options::="--root=/dpkg"` to get `apt` to forward the option to `dpkg` during extraction.

Comment: When I do stuff like this, I usually use a `debootstrap` to set up a minimal install.  Then I `chroot` into the directory and `apt install` from there.

Comment: @Stewart I am reading the documentation about the -o option. Where can I found documentation about "DPkg::options::='...'"? Never seen this syntax

Comment: It took me some time to figure out that syntax too.  I have references for that here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710702/is-there-an-apt-force-overwrite-option/710703#710703

Comment: Tried your suggestions but new errors arise. The first one is at timestamp 27.05: 'dpkg' is not found when handling perl-modules-5.32: pre-depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.17) (I have latest dpkg package installed though)

Comment: Looks like you may need to install to a chroot-ready directory.  See debootstrap to set one up.